# how to change the notification bottom title in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, html5-notifications

what key should I use in

**var notification = new Notification('hi', {
            icon: 'xxx.png',
            body: "click me",
        })**

to override the bottom text on notification ?

Comment: It's not clear how HTML5 Notification API you're referencing in your code is related to Chrome extensions that have their own [chrome.notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications).

Comment: @wOxxOm thx~, I find that it will use the value which map the key "name" in manifest.json (chrome extension)

Comment: It's still not clear why you can't use chrome.notifications API.

Comment: @wOxxOm after your mention, I change it to chrome.notifications API